# Django, обновление поля в классе UpdateView по условию

Tags: django

Есть модель Лот, как в UpdateView обновить поле current_rate по условию? условие: нужно чтобы новое значение было строго больше предыдущего

```
class Lot(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание')
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='lots')
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Автор лота', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner_lots', default=1)
current_buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Текущий покупатель', blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='buyer_bets', null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')
days_rate = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество дней размещения лота')
starting_rate = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Начальная ставка')
current_rate = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Текущая ставка', default=0, blank=True)
```

views:

```
class LotUpdateRateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Lot
    form_class = LotUpdateRateForm
    template_name = 'bet/lot_update_rate.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lot_list')
    success_message = "Ставка принята"
```

form:

```
class LotUpdateRateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    current_rate = forms.IntegerField(label='Текущая ставка', widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    current_buyer = forms.Select()
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста ваш views.py файл. И еще вопрос. Вам нужно чтобы current_rate менялся при каждом изменении формы?

Comment: Добавил выше. Нужно чтобы current_rate менялся только если новая ставка больше чем та которая была в БД до этого, если в поле формы записали ставку меньше текущей, то выдавалась ошибка "что нельзя делать ставку ниже предыдущей", Так же нужно чтобы менялся current_buyer при таком же условии (если этот самый текущий покупатель лота поставил ставку больше прежней

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите в вашем представлении  LotUpdateRateView метод form_valid

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        if (условие которое вам нужно для сохранения результата):
            self.object.current_rate = self.request.current_rate
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Могу ошибаться насчет self.request.current_rate , Пока еще сам плохо разбираюсь как вытягивать данные из формы, но должно сработать.
Данный метод отвечает за то что будет делать приложение, если все данные ввденные в форму верны, тут вы просто проверяете больше ли значение введенное в форме че то что у вас обозначено, и в случае True , меняете. Но если меньше делает уже то что считаете нужным.